# android: manifest.xml application nodes

Tags: android, manifest

in the manifest under application nodes I have to enter what activities, services, receivers my activity starts. some of them start with a dot, so I see something like

ActivityA

or

.ActivityB

What does the dot mean?

Thanks, A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the android [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html):

> However, as a shorthand, if the first
>   character of the string is a period,
>   the string is appended to the
>   application's package name (as
>   specified by the  element's
>   package attribute).

So it basically says that the Activity declared is located in the package defined in the  `manifest` tag